# PHP custom error handler to redirect or display error page when headers allready sent. Is this code a bad idea?

Tags: php, redirect, error-handling, custom-error-pages, custom-error-handling

I'm a novice writing a portable custom error handler which displays an error page when needed. The problem is, what to do if headers or html were already sent. You can't redirect and have no way of predicting what's already displayed in the browser.

I know that won't happen with good code. This is a last resort for those oh-crap-that-happened events.

The code works by plopping some pray-it-works html hacks into the page in an attempt to either force the browser to redirect, or failing that, display a nice error page in a division that pops up to hide whatever is already on the page.

Is the code below reasonable or ridiculous, or does PHP offer a better solution? Also, is there more I should do to make it solid?

```
<?PHP
// oh crap! something bad happened but...
// yay, my custom error handler caught it.
// It now does some error handler stuff, records the error, sends me a nasty email, etc.
// Decides the error was fatal. Time to display an error page.
// But wait! Alas, what if headers were sent?
// What if a single empty space was already sent to the browser?
// "ominous music".


if (!headers_sent()) {
    // whew! no problem. display a pretty error page.
}else{
    // dammit! somebodies getting fired. 
    // lets see if we can salvage this and show the viewer something nice.

    $mySafeErrorPage = "http://root.com/somePage.html";

    // Step one: Stop as much HTML as possible.
    // Dump anything still in the buffers.
    while (ob_get_level() > 0 && ob_get_status() != false) {
        ob_end_clean();
    }
    // Step two: Make sure our hack isn't stuck inside a comment or script.
    echo'// -- > </script>';

    // Step three: Make sure the safe page exist and is really safe.
    // Insert two redirect hacks. One for JavaScript. The other if script is disabled.
    $headersArray = @get_headers($mySafeErrorPage);
    $headersString = (is_array($headersArray))?implode("\n",$headersArray):$headersArray;
    $validated = (bool)preg_match('#HTTP/.*\s+[(200|301|302)]+\s#i',$headersString);
    if ($validated) {
        echo'
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            window.location.href="'.$mySafePage.'"
        </script>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url= '.$mySafeErrorPage.'" />';
    }

    // Step four: 
    // If we're still here, the redirect failed.
    // Display the error page in a giant pop-up block division 
    // to hide anything already sent to browser.
    echo'
    <div style = "z-index:9998;display:block;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;height:3000px;width:3000px;background-color:#FFF">
      <div style = "z-index:9999;display:block;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:300px;height:300px;background-color:#FFF;color:#000">
        MY HTTP 500 MESSAGE
      </div>     
    </div>';
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you're trying to fix the effect, not the cause of the problem. Secondly where would you place this code? Before the page is rendered? Won't work as no header are sent at this time. After the page is rendered? Won't work as all headers are sent at this time.

Another drawback of this code is the fact that the developers will need to remember to include it in every page, which could be cumbersome end error prone.

If you really want to avoid the "headers already sent" error, then add your custom my_header() function that wraps the header() PHP one and that makes the headers_sent() check. And disallow anyone else to use the PHP built-in function.

An example for my_header (function declaration copied from the original header() function):

```
function my_header($string, $replace = true, $http_response_code) {
    if(headers_sent()) {
        throw new Exception("Headers were already sent");
    }
    header($string, $replace, $http_response_code);
}
```

You can impose some rules on the project, like everyone having to use my_header() instead of header(), and during code review you can reject code that directly calls header(). If you're the only one on the project, then things are simpler :)

Comment: First, thanks so much for taking time to respond. I edited the post for better clarity.  I could use all the help possible. As to you first statement, where do i place it? answer is as soon as possible on the page. I know it shouldn't work. It's a nasty hack. But I've tested it over and over in every browser and it works every time no matter where I put it. I even copied this pages html. The hack worked no matter where I inserted it.           As for the second question. You jumped past my knowledge. I would love to understand that better.

Comment: I've edited my answer with more details about my first question and with an example on the custom implementation of the header() function.

Comment: I see what you're after. Thanks. I completely failed to make myself clear.  This code is meant to be part of a custom error  handler. No one would ever include it in a page. It would never be called at all. It has nothing to do with the header() function. The error handler would be included of course, as part of the bootstrap, or config page. It's for when an error occurs after text was ACCIDENTALLY sent to the browser.  I use "headers_sent()" because it's the closest test to know if something has been sent to the browser. _ But thanks for the info. The my_header() idea is a good one.

Comment: I still don't see the exact purpose of your code :) How are you planning to detect when the accidentally text was sent to the browser?

Comment: You can't detect if text was sent. But it happens. All you know is that if !headers_sent() fails, then something was sent to the browser. A status header? Empty space? PHP error message? Half a web page? Or you might have sent code as text, showing who knows what. The visitor is left with a blank page or a garbled mess. We know something's wrong or the error handler wouldn't have been called. If headers were sent, we can't set status, can't redirect, and don't know what the visitor is looking at. I thought the possibility of such an event was something an error handler should address.

Comment: I still fail to see how you'd use this code. Are you planning to do an include/require? Or will you wrap it inside a function? And when are you planning to call it?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand something basic. So step by step - and tell me if i misunderstand a step - this is what I think happens and is needed.    1) A nice error handler should display an error page in the event of a fatal PHP error.    2)To display an error page you must either redirect to an error page or print the complete page.    3) On rare occasions headers, or even html and text, may have already been sent before the error.  4) If headers or text were sent, PHP can no longer redirect or replace displayed content so you have a problem if that happens. (finished on next comment)

Comment: So my thought was to check if headers were sent before I try to redirect to, or print an error page. So this code comes after the error handler logs the error and before it attempts to display an error page. It assumes the worst, that unknown content was already sent. It first inserts a hack, which attempts to redirect to a safe html-only error page. It then attempts to hide whatever unknown content slipped though behind a large, absolute position division. So short answer: It comes just before the error page is displayed. Note: It is only called if headers were sent. Otherwise it is skipped.

Comment: What error page? Really doesn't change the question. Let's assume an error page exist.

Comment: And how does that error page happens to be rendered?

Comment: Rendered? I guess I'm not understanding the question. It's pure html. Only rendered in the client. Nothing server side. By client, I mean the browser. Just a plain ole web page.

Comment: Maybe you meant how will we get to the request. It is within a function. The error handler function is the very first thing loaded on every page and itself is called with an or die statement which outputs and error statement. In short if the error handler fails, no website. No php.

Comment: OK, firstly it looks like you didn't give the full code in the question, which is not ok. Secondly, who calls the function? The developer manually adds a call to that function, or is it automatically by the framework that you use? Thirdly, if it's called at the beginning then the function will pass, as no headers are sent at this time.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time. Of course the full code is several pages long. We seem caught in a loop. Although I sincerely appreciate the time you've spent responding, we seem to have a little trouble focusing on the question. Maybe when I finish the entire handler I'll put it on gethub. Thanks again for your time. Goodbye.

Comment: Yeah, the discussion was not very productive, it's best if we end it :) As closing thoughts, the code you posted seems a little bit complicated, and while it might work, what you're doing is to handle the effect of the bad code rather than fixing it. My suggestion from the answer addresses the root cause by not allowing developers to mistakenly send contents before the header() call.